# Why is the ASP.NET ListItem class sealed?

Tags: asp.net, listitem, sealed

I'm just curious. Why would the ASP.NET [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem) class need to be sealed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back then I read some interview with one of the creators of the BCL, I think it was with ScottGu.

IIRC he said something similar to "For some classes, we regretted that we made them sealed, and for other classes we regretted that we did not make them sealed".

So my assumption is that it was a design desicion that may not be completely transparent to us BCL users.

On the other hand, probably some 100k+ user knows more internals about it.

Comment: I regret that ListItem is sealed :) However a little projection of one data type to another using .NET 3.5+ helps alleviate the burden  `var listItems = ds.LoadAllPlaces().Select(place => new ListItem(place.Name, place.IdentityString));`